# Best way to speed up Django post requests?

Tags: django, raspberry-pi

I'm running a local Django server on a virtual machine that is remote interpreted onto a Raspberry Pi. The purpose of the remote connection is to have the Raspberry Pi upload a bunch of data from various sensors to the local server every minute.

I'm running into an issue now where the Post request speed is far too slow for the amount of data that will be coming in (Post speed is about one, sometimes two posts a second). I'm assuming this is due to the remote connection and the fact that it is running on a virtual machine as the post speed is exceptional if I run the local server on my physical laptop and post data from a local csv file, not remote interpreted.

I'm currently experimenting with the django bulk-create method to post data in bulk instead of hitting the database with every post, but I'm not sure if this will actually speed up the post requests. I'm worried it might just bottleneck the local server.

Does anybody know of a good way to speed up these requests? I'm using SQLite3, would switching to POSTGRE or a different database help?

**Code for Models.py**

```
class DataValue(models.Model):
     timestamp = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
     sensorName = models.TextField(null=True)
     valueName = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
     value = models.FloatField()
     units = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Comment: How do you models look? are you sending all the data to the same model?

Comment: Yes, if your sending large amounts of data using POSTGRE will sleep up the database queries. Apart from that the architecture of your models mater if your looking for efficiency and speed.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question to include my models.py. I am sending all the data to the same model. Would sending to multiple models speed up the requests? I'll also start looking into POSTGRE, thank you for that input!

Comment: Yes, i would spilt up the sensors. try it and let me know if it worked

Comment: So did performance improve enough? @LukeyP